# Economy printing in Canon PIXMA GM2070 series from my Android

Tags: printing

How to print in **economy mode from my Android** phone in my Canon PIXMA GM2070 model (ink tank printer - MONOCHROME)?

I can print in economy mode from my PC but I couldn't do that in my Android as the official Canon PRINT Inkjet/SELPHY app doesn't have an economy printing feature and it prints using high-standard and I want to save my ink.

Comment: It's an unusual situation but their own documentation for the app seems to confirm the absence of quality adjustments. So, in conclusion, what you want to do can't be done.